# AWS API Gateway: How to generate apiKey for my users and let them include it in query parameter?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Goal: We just want to let our customers use our HTTP endpoint by first generating an APIkey and then passing it in the request URI parameter to trigger lambda function.

What I tried: not sure how to generate an apiKey programmatically. Decided to test with my apiKey found in API Gateway and wrote the following code in Lambda function:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
   const apikey =
      event.queryStringParameters.apikey || event.stageVariables.apikey;

  const tmp = event.methodArn.split(":");
  const apiGatewayArnTmp = tmp[5].split("/");
  const awsAccountId = tmp[4];
  const region = tmp[3];
  const restApiId = apiGatewayArnTmp[0];
  const stage = apiGatewayArnTmp[1];

  callback(null, {
      principalId: "principalId",
      policyDocument: {
          Version: "2012-10-17",
          Statement: [
              {
                  Action: "execute-api:Invoke",
                  Effect: "Allow",
                  Resource: `arn:aws:execute-api:${region}:${awsAccountId}:${restApiId}/${stage}/*/*`
              }
          ]
      },
      usageIdentifierKey: apikey
  });

  return context.succeed('Success!');
};
```

In API Gateway, I've also added a custom authorizer with request querystring `apikey`.

When I click test and pass in any string value for the key querystring `apikey` I get the 200OK with the following:

```
Response
Response Code: 200
Latency 2607
Policy
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:2234235234:asdf3r3r/ESTestInvoke-stage/*/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I open `https://s9fs7h0.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/default/executeWSL?apikey=myAPIkeygoeshere` I still get `{"message":"Forbidden"}`

Where did I go wrong? I expected navigating that URL would've returned `Success!`

Comment: I see you are building the resource manually, don't do that, just use `event.methodArn` as the resource in the returned policy.  I am not sure if there is some defect in that logic that creates that.  Also, are you using usage plans and is that where you get your api key? I think the "usageIdentifierKey" is only valid for usage plan api keys so you may remove that if that is not what you are doing.

Comment: I decided to just create a User table and match user email to a key and check the dynamodb :/ theres a limit of 10,000 per account apparently if you use usage plans